# Exporting transparent background using Fireworks

Tags: graphics, transparency, fireworks

I'm pretty new to Fireworks. I drew an orange rectangle and made it semi-transparent. My web page has a patterned background which I'd like to be able to see through my div, but I can't change the opacity of the div in CSS as the div contains other divs that also become transparent using this CSS when I don't want them to!

I've tried loads of things I found on Google but to no avail. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to export the semi-transparent rectangle from Fireworks so it stays that way, just make sure your canvas color is set to none (the box with a red diagonal line through it) and then export it as a PNG-32.

I'm not sure I understood what you mean by DIVs becoming transparent when using CSS. Can you elaborate on that a bit?